# Filter RC passive - Calculate fz y fp

Tags: filter

Friends, I need your help ... I have to solve this circuit and I can not find the solution ... I need to find the cut frequencies fz and fp ... could you help me please? ...

[image]

Comment: How to determine the transfer function in order to find the pole and zero is explained in many books. Explain why that explanation is not good enough for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework without effort shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of transfer function is determined in a snapshot using the FACTs described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). Look at the below drawing. First, determine the transfer function for \$s=0\$: open the cap and see what gain you have. Obviously, this is 1. Then, reduce the input voltage (the stimulus) to 0 V and determine the resistance "seen" from the capacitor connecting terminals.

[image]

You have the series connection of the two resistances. The time constant is therefore \$\tau=(R_1+R_2)C_1\$. The pole is immediate as it is the inverse of the time constant for a 1-st order circuit: \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{1}{C_1(R_1+R_2)}\$. The zero is little trickier as you have to find the network condition which nulls the response despite the presence of the excitation. In this transformed circuit, if \$V_{in}\$ is back, then you have a null in the response if the series connection of \$R_2\$ and \$C_1\$ realizes a transformed short circuit. The zero is thus tuned at \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{C_1R_2}\$. The below Mathcad sheet shows the magnitude and phase response of the complete transfer function.

[image]